# Generate vector that groups (by name) columns in a new vector in R

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, grouping, tidyr

I have a dataset like **original** with numeric (NP) and binary (all the rest) variables (my dataset is much larger and includes way more numeric and dummies):

```
NP <- c(4,6,18,1,3,12,8)
iso_mode_USA <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
iso_mode_CHN <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
iso_mode_COL <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
iso_mode_mod_USA <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
iso_mode_mod_CHN <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
iso_mode_mod_COL <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
exp_sector_4 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
exp_sector_5 <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
exp_sector_7 <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
original <- data.frame(NP, iso_mode_USA, iso_mode_CHN, iso_mode_COL, iso_mode_mod_USA, iso_mode_mod_CHN, iso_mode_mod_CHN, exp_sector_4, exp_sector_5, exp_sector_7)
```

I want to have a vector that records the group of each column by the start of their names (e.g. NP forms one group, iso_mode_ forms another group, exp_sect_ forms another group and so on...). Therefore, the **vector** looks like:

```
vector <- c("1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4")
```

Any idea on how to do it in dplyr (for many more variables)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grepl` to find the *name* and `which` in `apply` to get the position.

```
tt <- paste0("^", unique(sub("_[^_]+$", "_", names(original))), "([^_]+$|$)")
apply(sapply(tt, grepl, names(original)), 1, which)
# [1] 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4
```

Comment: Great solution! Due to the large amount of columns I have (+1700) I may not even see the patterns of all columns. Therefore, is there a way in which I can automatise the process of selecting the variables (i.e. R identifies the names NP, iso_mode_, exp_sector, etc)?

Comment: Another issue I have is that when I apply the code to my data (where I have a dataframe composed also by character and factor variables) I get a list as an outcome, and is not repeating the number for a given group

Comment: Is there a direct way from your code to get back the names identified in "tt"?

Comment: Do you mean the result of this: `unique(sub("_[^_]+$", "_", names(original)))` ?